# culturally neutral TryParse

Tags: c#

I have the following extension method

```
public static bool IsValidCurrency(this string value)
{
    CultureInfo culture = new CultureInfo ("en-gb");
    decimal result;
    return decimal.TryParse(value, NumberStyles.Currency, culture, out result);
}
```

I wish to have this to be culturally neutral allowing to pass $ , €, ¥ etc. into the method

Thanks

Comment: what is the problem with this ??

Comment: Maybe you should try using `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` instead of passing the specific `CultureInfo`

Comment: Pranay Rana I may not know what currency I am dealing with all the time so I want to be able to pass any form of currency into the method not just GB £ as shown above

Comment: V4Vendetta  CultureInfo.InvariantCulture  this does not seem to work for me anyway.

Comment: I guess you will have to lookup for the currency and create your own formatter which specifies the currency like `MyNumberFormat.CurrencySymbol = "¥"` and then parse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Different cultures may use the same currency symbol to mean different things. Hence there is no invariant way to read a currency.

It could however be done in the following way:

```
public static bool IsValidCurrency(this string value)
{       
    decimal result;
    var cultures = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.SpecificCultures);
    return cultures.Any(info => Decimal.TryParse(value, NumberStyles.Currency, info, out result));
}
```

Comment: +1 for "Different cultures may use the same currency symbol to mean different things".

Comment: @burrows If this is right, is there any chance you could mark the answer as correct? Simply click the tick next to the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

My initial thought is that passing in a currency symbol to such a method without context means it might be a valid symbol, but not necessarily the *correct* one - many regions use the '$' symbol, for example.

If I were doing this anyway, I'd probably loop round the specific .NET cultures (avoiding the Invariant Culture, if you're on Windows 7), checking each RegionInfo's CurrencySymbol property against the string passed in. This is quick, dirty (and **untested**) while it's still in my head; I'm sure this could be more efficiently coded:

```
public static Boolean IsValidCurrency(this string value)
{
  // Assume the worst.
  Boolean isValid = false;

  foreach (CultureInfo c in CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.SpecificCultures))
  {
    // Account for InvariantCulture weirdness in Windows 7.
    if (!c.Equals(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
    {
      RegionInfo r = new RegionInfo(c.LCID);

      if (r.CurrencySymbol.Equals(value, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
      {
        // We've got a match, so flag it and break.
        isValid = true;
        break;
      }
    }
  }

  return isValid;
}
```

This assumes you're only passing in the symbol, and doesn't solve the variant uses of different symbols. Hope this gets you thinking, anyway.

Comment: Rather than creating a new `RegionInfo`, would it not be equivalent to call `c.NumberFormat.CurrencySymbol`?

Comment: You're right - no reason why you couldn't do that in this context. In the case of my implementation, I need to ensure that the information retrieved per region is independent of the user's culture (http://forums.asp.net/t/1093381.aspx) since we're displaying items in multiple currencies, but still using the current culture's number formatting.

Comment: That makes sense, I've not done much with cultures and globalization, so the link and your explanation were very useful, thanks :)